Nested query in Django, need to compare the processing time
time_limit = timezone.now() - timedelta(hours=30) time_limit_str =
time_limit.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  

in_review_records = RequestedData.objects.filter(
    Q(status='In Review') &
    (
        Q(additional_details__isnull=True) |
        Q(additional_details__processing_details__isnull=True) |
        (
            Q(additional_details__processing_details__has_key=account_name) & 
            Q(additional_details__processing_details__account_name__lte=time_limit_str)
        ) |
        (
            Q(additional_details__processing_details__isnull=False) &  
            ~Q(additional_details__processing_details__has_key=account_name)
        )
    ) ).annotate(processing_details=KeyTransform('processing_details', 'additional_details')).annotate(account_name=KeyTransform(account_name,
'processing_details'))

I am trying to get all the records where:

if the additional_details is empty
if processing_details in additional_details is empty
if processing_details has key account
then check the value (which is processing time ) is not in past 30 hours
and if processing_details has keys but it is not "abc" we are free to include it

I tried so many things but nothing seems to work
Finally, the format of additional_details which is a JSON model field is like this JSONField(default=dict, null=True, blank=True)
{
  "additional_details" : {
    "processing_details": {
      "account1": "2024-07-19 11:03:20",
      "account2": "2024-07-20 11:03:20",
      "account3": "2024-07-23 11:03:20"
    }
}


and this is one of the (very) many reasons not to use JSON blobs: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/non-atomic-jsonfield-s.html
